# Tabular display of divs using css

Tags: css

EDIT: I have clarified why I do not really want tables.

I have the following html:

```
<div id="heading">
   <span class="name">name</span> 
   <span class="age">age</span> 
</div> 
<div class="person">
   <span class="name">Sam</span> 
   <span class="age">1</span>
   <span class="description">This is a person description</span> 
</div> 
<div class="person">
   <span class="name">Bob bob</span> 
   <span class="age">2</span> 
   <span class="description">This is another person description</span>
</div>
```

I would like to render a pixel perfect table like structure:

```
       name         age
       ---------------------------------------------

       Sam          1

       This is a person description  

       ---------------------------------------------

       Bob bob      2

       This is another person description

       ---------------------------------------------
```

What css can I use for this?

To me this seems to fit a bit better in divs as opposed to a table, but if the same markup can be altered to be a table, without introducing non-semantic rows, I would be happy to go with a table.

Comment: Wow, thanks for completely changing the specification after 3 answers. =_=

Comment: I'm sorry. I can post another question if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
*.name { float:left; clear:left; width:200px; }
*.age { float:left; width:200px; }

div.heading, div.person { clear:both; overflow:hidden; zoom:1; }
```

^ Hypothetically this would be it but semantically your markup should stay as a table, and mark it up as:

```
 <table summary="Your Summary">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Bob bob</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: * is a terrible selector to use. You should use div.name and div.age.

Comment: Only reason I chose it is because his inner element node names were inconsistent. I would opt with the updated table markup I used. 

I probably wouldn't ever use * except for simplistic base styles in my reset.css.

Comment: Why not go with a simple `.name` selector?

Comment: because I was influenced by Michael Bowers' style.

Comment: apologies, I slightly changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just say that considering this is tabular data, it is not very semantic to use `<div>` tags... Semantic HTML is all about using the proper tag to represent the data being outputted, regardless of the display. Moving on.

You can use the following CSS to display it in a tabular way:

```
.heading, .person {
    clear: both;
}
.heading {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.heading .name,
.person  .name {
    display: block;
    width: 40em; /* for a table of 50em */
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.heading .age,
.person  .age {
    width: 10em; /* for a table of 50em */
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.heading .description,
.person  .description {
    width: 50em; /* for a table of 50em */
    display: block;
    clear: left;
}
```

Now, since you modified your original question to allow the use of tables:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">This is a person description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob bob</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">This is another person description</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And no CSS required!

Comment: apologies, I slightly changed the question.

Comment: **@Sam Saffron:** I modified my answer.

Comment: Andrew, the issue I have with the table version, is that the "td colspan="2" feels a bit non-semantic, instead of each row in the table representing a user I would have 2 rows representing a user. Which would make addressing them in jQuery more complicated etc.

Comment: Semantic? "This is a person description" stands alone? No. It relates (in a child sense) to Sam, which the table structure loses.
Or put another way, what does each of your table rows describe?

Comment: **@Stephen:** There is so much you can do if you want to display it below. It's as close as you'll get. It's still more semantic than using `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.name, .age {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.name {
    width: 15em; /* change to fit needs */
}

/* consider adding the following */
.age {
    margin-left: 15em /* same as or greater than above width */
}

.person {
    clear: left;
}

#heading div {
    font-weight: bold;
    /* other fancy markup for heading style */
}
```

Comment: apologies, I slightly changed the question.